# coxme proportional hazard assumption

Tags: r, cox-model

I am running mixed effect Cox models (I have 1 random effect factor) using the `coxme` function {`coxme`} in R, and I would like to check the assumption of proportional hazard.

I know that the proportional hazards (PH) assumption can be verified with the `cox.zph` function {`survival`} on `cox.ph` model.

However, I cannot find the equivalent for `coxme` models.

In 2015 a similar question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401706/r-proportional-hazard-assumption-in-coxme), but had no answer.

My questions are:

1. How to test PH assumption on mixed effect cox model `coxme`?
2. If there is no equivalent of the `cox.zph` for `coxme` models, is it valid for publication in scientific article to run mixed effect `coxme` model but test the PH assumption on a `cox.ph` model identical to the `coxme` model but without random effect?

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for making this a separate answer, but I cannot comment because I have less than 50 reputation.

Oka suggested using frailty in connection with `coxph` in order to test the proportional hazard assumption.  I believe it is worth noting that the [documentation for frailty](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.44-1.1/topics/frailty) mentions, "the `coxme` package has superseded this [`frailty`] method."  For this reason, the original question about "how to test the PH assumption on mixed effect cox model `coxme`," has strong justification to stay within the scope of `coxme`.

Comment: Apologies don't get around the fact that you shouldn't use answers for comments before you get sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 2):

*However, I cannot find the equivalent for coxme models.*

---

Based on the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf), you *can* add the random effects into Cox or survreg model with `frailty` function. As suggested in [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394364/coxme-proportional-hazard-assumption), you can do it like this:

```
# making the model
myfit <- coxph( Surv(Time, Censor) ~ fixed + frailty(random) , data = mydata )

# assessing the proportionality of hazards
cox.zph(myfit)
```

*How to test PH assumption on mixed effect cox model coxme?*

---

With `coxme` you could probably use model residuals for diagnostics. The objects produced by `lmekin` or `lmer` functions have been [mentioned](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2015-01-29/web/packages/coxme/coxme.pdf) to have methods for residuals. And when you get them, you can plot them and examine graphically or otherwise.

*If there is no equivalent of the `cox.zph` for `coxme` models, is it valid for publication in scientific article to run mixed effect `coxme` model but test the PH assumption on a `cox.ph` model identical to the `coxme` model but without random effect?*

---

There is no reason for that, since you *can* test the PH with random effects with cox.zph/cox.ph and get more accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

The proportional hazards (PH) assumption for fixed effects in a `coxme` model can be tested with the same `cox.zph()` function used for `coxph` models. As the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) of `cox.zph()` states, its `fit` argument is "the result of fitting a Cox regression model, using the `coxph` **or `coxme`** functions." (Emphasis added.)

As another answer notes, the random effects in a `coxme` model cannot be evaluated for PH, as the modeling process treats the random effects as fixed offsets. I *suspect* that failures of PH with respect to random effects (whatever that might mean in this context) would thus show up as PH violations in fixed effects.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67709136/5044791) illustrates the successful use of `cox.zph()` on a `coxme` object, at least with fairly recent versions of the software (`survival_3.1-11` and `coxme_2.2-16`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) in the page 31, "cox.zph" does not work for the "frailty" function.

Therefore, you can not use cox.zph(myfit) to check mixed effects Cox models as the answers Oka or kjg suggested above.

> Random effects terms such a frailty or random effects in a coxme model are not checked for proportional hazards, rather they are treated as a fixed offset in model.

Comment: The note in the manual for `cox.zph` that you cite only applies to the random-effect terms. According to the manual, the fixed-effect terms in a `coxme` model can still be evaluated for PH with `cox.zph()`. Those fixed effects will typically be of most interest in terms of evaluating PH.